# How to align text at the top and left in a quarto div container?

Tags: html, css, pdf, latex, quarto

I'm trying to create a Quarto pdf document with a grid layout of three rows and two columns. In the top left div container, I want to have text (a list of bullet points) and in the other five containers I want to have charts or tables.

Getting the grid layout to work wasn't a problem, but trying to get the text in the upper left div container to be aligned at the top rather than centered vertically has proved to be more difficult than it seems it should be.

Here's a minimum reproducible example of the Quarto code that I'm using:

```
---
format: 
  pdf:
    pdf-engine: xelatex
    documentclass: article
    geometry:
      - left=1cm
      - right=1cm
      - top=2cm
      - bottom=1cm
    mainfont: Open Sans
    include-in-header: 
      text: |
        \usepackage{fancyhdr}
        \pagestyle{fancy}
        \usepackage{tikz}
        \usepackage{lipsum}
        \usepackage{etoolbox}
        \patchcmd{\chapter}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{\thispagestyle{fancy}}{}{}
        
        \definecolor{gmitblue}{RGB}{0,32,96}
        
        \usetikzlibrary{calc}
        \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
        
        \fancyhf{}
        \fancyhead[C]{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]%
            \fill[gmitblue] (current page.north west) rectangle ($(current page.north east)+(0,-0.75in)$);
            \node[anchor=north west, text=white, font=\Large\scshape, minimum size=0.75in, inner xsep=5mm] at (current page.north west) {Report title};
            \node[anchor=north east, minimum size=0.75in, inner xsep=5mm] at (current page.north east) {\includegraphics[height=0.8cm,keepaspectratio]{generic_logo.png}};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        }
        
        \setlength{\headheight}{12pt}
---

::: {layout-nrow="3"}

<div style='vertical-align: top; text-align: left;'>
## Executive Summary
 * Bullet 1
 * Bullet 2
 * Bullet 3
 * Bullet 4
 * Bullet 5
</div>

![](some_plot.png){width="3.33in"}

![](some_plot.png){width="3.33in"}

![](some_plot.png){width="3.33in"}

![](some_plot.png){width="3.33in"}

![](some_plot.png){width="3.33in"}
:::
```

And attached is what the output looks like. As one can see the text in the upper left hand container appears to be centered vertically, rather than starting at the top. I've also attached the placeholder chart and logo, in case someone wants to try to recreate the situation.

[image: Quarto PDF Output]
[image: some_plot.png]
[image: generic_logo.png]

Comment: Quarto docs say they're using Bootstrap 5 for layout. Bootstrap 5 is using Flexbox. To align a child element to the top within Flexbox parent you select the child element and apply `align-self: flex-start;` You can also use `align-self: stretch;` the difference will be visible if you have a distinguishing background color on the child. Try that in your inline style attribute on the div.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, @prkos. Much appreciated. It doesn't seem to change the outcome, however, if I use <div style='align-self: flex-start;'> or <div style='align-self: stretch;'>. The alignment is still in the center and it's potentially looking like this is a reported issue (reported last week) in Quarto: https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/issues/9109. Thus, I may have to wait to see how the issue gets resolved. But thanks again for taking the time to suggest a solution.

Comment: It might be. Have you tried the `layout-valign="top"` from the reported issue? It's different from your style attribute example. They seems to have specific attributes for layout so that may be the way to go instead of a regular CSS style attribute.

Comment: Yep, I originally tried that approach (layout-valign = 'top') and then a whole host of other approaches. No luck!

Comment: I guess your best option is to ask Quarto about the layout method they use and how to override it.